# a problem about minimum value

Tags: real-analysis

Calculate \begin{equation*}\text{min}_{a,b,c}\int^1_{-1}|x^3-a-bx-cx^2|^2dx.\end{equation*}
I want to solve it by the theory in  Hilbert space $L^2(-1,1)$,but I don't know how to start.Can anyone give me a help?

Comment: You need to determine $a,b,c$ explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we know from the integration bounds: $-1<x<1$. Thereof, if $b,c>0$, we deduce that:
$$-1<x^3<1$$
$$-c<-cx^2<0$$
$$b<-bx<-b$$
which by summing up results
$$-1-c+b-a<x^3-cx^2-bx-a<1-b-a$$
1) If the left-hand side (LHS) is negative and the right-hand side (RHS) is positive, i.e.:

$-1-c+b-a\leq 0$ and $1-b-a\geq 0$, the minimum of the integral is $0$.

2) If the LHS and RHS are both negative, i.e.:

$-1-c+b-a\leq 0$ and $1-b-a\leq  0$, the minimum of the integral is $2(1-b-a)^2$.

3) If the LHS and RHS are both positive, i.e.:

$-1-c+b-a\geq 0$ and $1-b-a\geq  0$, the minimum of the integral is $2(-1-c+b-a)^2$.

You can do the same for $b,c<0$ or other possible conditions.

Comment: That's a so elementary answer,thank you.

Comment: You are welcome.